# How Can I Float A View Over A Displayed Popover, in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uipopovercontroller

I can produce a small project to illustrate this, but I think it's faster, and easier, if I simply describe it.

I have [this widget I wrote](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_AutofillTextField). It displays a "floating" UITableView over everything else. It does this by adding itself to the main window root view controller.

However, if I am trying to display it in a popover, the table comes up *under* the popover. I should add that it will overlap the popover boundaries. It should not be contained in the popover.

What's the most correct way to get it to appear over the popover?

Comment: I have -sort of- solved it, by attaching to the actual window object, which is a UIView. However, I'm not sure how "correct" it is to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I solved this, by simply attaching the table to the main `view.window` instance.

This seems to work in all my tests (including things like split view, and popover view).

I have not read anything that indicates that I should not do this. Apple has already passed a couple of TestFlight releases that have it, so it didn't ring any alarms for them.

Comment: Glad you figured out and posted the answer ,it'll be helpful for everyone

Comment: I do that. I find this resource valuable, and try to be a good citizen.